# How to enter a value while running UIAutomation Test on iOS Simulator or Device

Tags: ios, automated-tests, instruments, ui-automation, ios-ui-automation

I want to enter a value while UIAutomation is testing, but i don't know how.
The case:

1- In js usercode and password have been setted and button tapped.
2-After that phone receives a message including the code.

The code must be entered to textfiled.

Is it possible to give the code while test is running?

Thanks

Comment: How would your simulator receive the message?  Is it SMS or some other method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The phone receives a text message that you want to read from in your test? I'm pretty certain that's impossible. You can't really leave the app you are running the test on. If you're running from a simulator your best bet would be to somehow write the code to a file somewhere and read it using `UIAHost.performTaskWithPathArgumentsTimeout`

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIAutomation/Reference/UIAHostClassReference/index.html#//apple_ref/javascript/instm/UIAHost/performTaskWithPathArgumentsTimeout